# signingConf.storeFile not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just loaded Android Studio 3.2.1 after removing earlier versions. I now get the following message:
.android\debug.keystore .. property signingConf.storeFile does not exist. Earlier posts have not been helpful as I'm not trying to create a certificate, just trying to create and execute a project from  scratch without interfering with the gradle files.
Running with debug yields the following:
9:19:18.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: File 'D:\Kotlin_Android\Projecfts\TheApplication\app\D:Android.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist.
19:19:18.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskValidationContext$Severity$2.report(TaskValidationContext.java:51)
19:19:18.751 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   ... 26 more

Comment: Check whether you don't have a signingconfig referred in your debug flavor in app build gradle file

Comment: Because of the mentioned bug ":\Kotlin_Android\Projecfts\TheApplication\app\D:Android.android\debug.keystore' specified for property 'signingConfig.storeFile' does not exist." the file app-debug.apk is not generated. Further one cannot generate either the default or a custom apt. Again I have used the defaults to produce the app.